# JavaScript Inheritance Object.call() undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance

I am attempting to create an object-oriented approach to my program. I read that this should create an inheritance of World from Sprite with Sprite being the parent, but Sprite.call(this, imagePath) comes up as imagePath is undefined. I would assume the other variables in the call would also be undefined. How do I appropriately call the parent variables?

```
   function Sprite(spriteX, spriteY, spriteW, spriteH, scale, positionX, positionY, direction)
                {
                    this.imagePath = world_sprite;
                    this.spriteX = spriteX;
                    this.spriteY = spriteY;
                    this.spriteW = spriteW;
                    this.spriteH = spriteH;
                    this.scale = scale;
                    this.positionX = positionX;
                    this.positionY = positionY;
                    this.direction = direction;
                    this.speed = 5;

                    this.noGravity = false;
                    this.direction = 0;

                    //Physics stuff
                    this.velX = 0;
                    this.velY = 0;
                    this.friction = 0.98;
                };

    function World(posX, posY, direction, xOffset, yOffset)
                {
                    Sprite.call(this, imagePath, positionX, positionY, direction);

                    this.spriteX = 0;
                    this.spriteY = 0;
                    this.spriteW = 400;
                    this.spriteH = 400;
                    this.scale = 0.4;

                    this.xOffset = xOffset;
                    this.yOffset = yOffset;
                    this.lives = 3;
                };
```

Comment: Inside the `World()` function, you have no variables or parameters named `imagePath`, `positionX`, or `positionY`. So of course those are undefined.

Comment: I assumed Sprite.call would get those variables from Sprite?

Comment: No, `Sprite.call()` is calling *into* the `Sprite()` function. At the point where you make the call, there is no knowledge of what goes on inside that function. You have to use only what you have available at that point. See my answer below for one way you could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could accomplish what it looks like you're trying to do:

```js
function Sprite(
   spriteX, spriteY, spriteW, spriteH,
   scale, positionX, positionY, direction
) {
    this.imagePath = world_sprite;
    this.spriteX = spriteX;
    this.spriteY = spriteY;
    this.spriteW = spriteW;
    this.spriteH = spriteH;
    this.scale = scale;
    this.positionX = positionX;
    this.positionY = positionY;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.speed = 5;

    this.noGravity = false;
    this.direction = 0;

    //Physics stuff
    this.velX = 0;
    this.velY = 0;
    this.friction = 0.98;
};

function World(
    posX, posY, direction, xOffset, yOffset
) {
    Sprite.call( this, 0, 0, 400, 400, 0.4, posX, posY, direction );

    this.xOffset = xOffset;
    this.yOffset = yOffset;
    this.lives = 3;
};
```

Comment: So this would also inherit the imagePath?

Answer (score 0):

You have `Sprite.call(this, imagePath, positionX, positionY, direction);` but the arguments to `Sprite` don't match this.

Comment: So the variables need to be in the argument for Sprite? I was hoping I didn't have to pass those for them to be inherited...

Comment: You either have to define them in ```World``` itself or pass it in to ```Sprite``` so that ```Sprite``` can define it.

Comment: And how did you pass them into ```Sprite```?